# Cosine similarity output different for different libraries

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I am trying to find the cosine distance between two n-dimensional vectors. I did so by using both scipy and sklearn. Somehow the output of the two libraries are different. I am not able to understand why.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial
from sklearn import metrics
a=np.array([1,2,3,4])
b=np.array([2,3,1,4])
X=np.array([a,b])
print spatial.distance.pdist(X,'cosine')[0]
print metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(a,b)[0][0]
print metrics.pairwise_distances(np.reshape(a,(1,4)),np.reshape(b,(1,4)),metric = 'cosine')[0][0]
```

Output of this code is as follows:

```
0.1

0.9

0.1
```

Comment: I believe `0.9` is the cosine of the angle between `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that one time you calculate the cosine *distance* (`spatial.distance.pdist`, `metrics.pairwise_distances`), whereas the other time you are calculating cosine *similarity* (`metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity`).

So `cosine_distance = 1 - cosine_similarity`, which explains why the `distance` between two data points in your example is `0.1`, and the `similarity` between the two is `0.9`.

`scipy` generally calculates distances, and if you look at the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html), cosine distance is actually defined as `1 - cosine_similarity` there.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. At least for this example. But I got output greater than 1.0 in case of pdist and pairwise distances. That confused me further. I should really have given a different example.

Comment: Can you provide that example? In any case, `cosine similarity` is only defined in the range `[0, 1]` if your feature vectors don't contain negative values (hence the angle won't be greater than 90º for feature vectors with only positive values).

Comment: My feature vectors did contain negative values. I just checked. The pdist came out to be 1.07250622457 while cosine_similarity gave an output of -0.0725063. So I figured out the range in which these two functions have been defined is just different. They are doing the same thing. Thanks.